# Bootstrap Printing and Column Resizing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have done some digging on SO and have found a a variety of resources regarding printing and bootstrap.css, but I have not seen a solution to this particular problem.

Lets say I have a setup like seen in this Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7ETXQyEvY7S16JTU9wYB?p=preview

and HTML like this:

```
   <div class="col-xs-6 red">
      testing
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 blue hidden">
      123
    </div>
```

The CSS states that during printing the column will be hidden (on my real page the stle is not `hidden` but `hidden-print`), which is expected, but is there anyway to now have the `col-xs-6 red` now take up the empty space left by the hidden blue column.

I know you could override the style `col-xs-6` to be `width:100%`, but that would affect other columns on the page that need to be left at `width: 50%`.

Has anyone had this problem before, if so how did you address it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest something like:

```
@media print {  
   .col-print-12{
       width:100% !important;
   }
}
```

Then your HTML can be:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-print-12 bg-danger">
  Red Column is full width for print
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 hidden-print bg-primary">
  Blue Column is hidden for print
</div>
```

`!important` is needed to override the regular col widths since at least one set will also apply at print width.

I updated your plunk using [xs as a proxy for the print view here](http://plnkr.co/edit/B8Le6fPmvTLSPcjIamG3?p=preview) to demonstrate the concept.  One red column in mobile, Red and Blue columns in tablet or bigger.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I needed the site to be visible on most mobile devices so I tried not to make one size the default printing.

Answer (score 5):

For Bootstrap 4 you need to do a modification from @Lance's answer.

```
@media print {
  .col-print-12 {
    max-width: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
}
```

With the same HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-print-12 bg-danger">
  Red Column is full width for print
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 hidden-print bg-primary">
  Blue Column is hidden for print
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit: if you want to do it with CSS only you would have to use the `flex` property. Take a look at this [pen](http://codepen.io/Lizardan/pen/JdVPdK). Change `display: flex` to `display: none` on any column and see how they stretch to fit the available space (this renders bootstrap useless).

Create a `div` container inside the bootstrap column and apply `visibility: hidden` to it. You want to hide without removing it, meaning the browser will still show the space that the element occupies.

It's a good practice not to add your own classes to bootstrap columns but instead create a container inside it so you can apply your classes to.

`display: none` gets rid of the element entirely and affects the positioning of the other elements that were around it.

Comment: The `hidden` bootstrap class which is `hidden-print` when printing does apply that style, but the column remains 50% of the parent container. You can see their usages in the plnkr.

Comment: So you want the hidden column to go away and not take up any space?

Comment: That's correct, which means that ideally the `col-xs-6 red` would function more like a `col-xs-12 red`. I'm not entirely sure this is doable, because the `col-xs-6 red` will always calculate 50% width, as it does not care about its siblings, but mainly its parent.

Comment: You need to apply the new `col-xs-12` class with javascript to the red column once the blue one is `hidden`.

Comment: I can't use 100% width on the red element cause it then be 100% when the blue div is visible. The blue div would then be pushed down to the next line.

Comment: +1 For non-bootstrap solution. Worth noting that flex related solutions are more recent and do not work on some more recent browsers EG: Pre-Firefox 28.